# Como exibir imagens no symfony

Tags: symfony

Estou iniciando no symfony e gostaria de saber qual a forma correta de exibir uma imagem.
Estou alterando o index.html.twing e que fica em app/resource/view/default/ e o base.html.twing que fica em app/resource/view/.
Eu coloquei `<img src="../../../src/AppBundle/Resources/public/imagens/logo.png" />`

```
<img src="{{ asset('imagens/dev-total-logo.png') }}" />
```

Como é a forma correta de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma correta é a segunda:

```
<img src="{{ asset('imagens/dev-total-logo.png') }}" />
```

Há diversas razões para isso. A primeira delas é que dessa forma sua aplicação consegue exibir a imagem independente de onde ficar sua pasta de arquivos estáticos, desde que o Symfony saiba onde ela esteja.

Além disso, as imagens (bem como qualquer outro arquivo estático, como um arquivo CSS ou um arquivo JS) devem estar na pasta `web/`. Caso seus arquivos estáticos estejam dentro de um *bundle*, ou seja, inacessíveis, é necessário fazer uso do comando `assets:install` para que os arquivos sejam copiados (ou vinculados) na pasta pública.

No Symfony 2.x:

```
app/console assets:install
```

No Symfony 3.x:

```
bin/console assets:install
```

Comment: Eu estava colocando os arquivos em src/AppBundle/Resources/public/imagens/. Eu movi para a pasta Web e funcionou.

Comment: Não é necessário mover, você pode deixar os arquivos lá, se quiser, e só usar o comando acima para publicá-las. :) A vantagem é que você mantém os arquivos estáticos separados por bundle, sem precisar misturar tudo.

Comment: Eu usei mais deu erro.